# Model with two ordinal variables

Tags: econometrics, model, ordinal-data

I have question about the ordinal variables in model and using them correctly. Let's say I have a model that explains income by education and age.

Age is continous and education is ordinal ex. can be low, medium and high.

So I would specify model this way:

$Income = \beta_0 + \beta_1age + \beta_2mediumEduc+\beta_3highEduc$

Well I'm not 100% sure why I would omit the $lowEduc$ variable (I recall doing the same with seasonal dummy variables in Econometrics classes; does it have something to do with collinearity?). But I understand the fact that lowEduc is base line and $\beta_0$ is somehow describing it.

That being said, let's move to my actual question. What about the situation in which I have two ordinal variables ex. education, and size of the city - small, medium, big.

Should I also specify model this way with omitting one of the levels:

$Income = \beta_0 + \beta_1age + \beta_2mediumEduc+\beta_3highEduc + \beta_4mediumCity+\beta_5bigCity$

This somehow doesn't seem right.

Comment: What is your questions exactly besides that it doesn't feel right?

Comment: My question is - is it right way to specify model or should I include all levels of one of ordinal variables?

Comment: Okey I see, I'll think you'll find the answer to your question by trail and error. As this is a self-study question I urge you to try to include either   loweduc or    smallCity and see what happens.

Hint: You where on to something when you talked about "something to do with collinearity".  See [dummy variable trap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29).